# position: fixed goes off of the screen

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am using `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` to affix something to the bottom of the screen. The name, however, appears to go off of the screen, on my 11" Air, and you can see the site [here](http://sciencewebsite.snapapps.c9.io/index.php?name=StackOverflow). I've posted my CSS code below for the div.
Broken JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgdQv/

```
#credits {

    color: #363636;
bottom: 0;
padding-right: 10em;
text-align: right;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transition:1.5s;
  -ms-transition:1.5s;
  -moz-transition:1.5s;
  -webkit-transition:1.5s;
  transition:1.5s;

}
#credits:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;

}
```

Comment: I removed the footer code from the demo for a second, it should be back.

Comment: Please post a screenshot from your laptop, that would give us a clue as to what to look for, also, post some HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `right: 30px` (30px being the value of `margin-right` of parent body) and it should behave as expected.
Edit: and maybe remove `padding-right: 10em`. Forgot that I had desactivated it in Firebug before answering...

Also do not post link to a website: after you've fixed your problem, your question will become meaningless to future visitors of this question because the link will have changed... Please post relevant HTML and CSS reproducing your problem (and a fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

You only must add an height-attribute to your #credits.